# Wordpress translation words in a page

Tags: wordpress, translation

I want to translate the Happening, Upcoming and Expired words in the given link to my language. But I cannot find a file which contains these words or events page in my pages. How can I find the source of these words?

[balikesirkolej.com](http://balikesirkolej.com/events/)

Comment: That is kinda hard to tell the code location without checking the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your theme source code to review. You can do it with jQuery-

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        $("a[href='#tab-happening']:contains('Happening')").text("Tab1 Headline");
        $("a[href='#tab-upcoming']:contains('Upcoming')").text("Tab2 Headline");
        $("a[href='#tab-expired']:contains('Expired')").text("Tab3 Headline");  
    })( jQuery );   
</script>
```